# How to efficiently filter large amount of records based on user permissions on specific records with specific criteria?

Tags: sql, architecture, data-access-layer

I'm working as a maintainer for a legacy Java-based cargo railway consignment note accounting system. There is a serious performance issue with retrieving a list of consignment notes to display on their website.

I cannot publish the entire query, but here are some statistics to give the general idea:

- it has 17 left joins
- it has a huge `where` clause with 5 OR groups to determine if a user is allowed to access a record because of a specific relation to the record (consignor, consignee, carrier, payer, supervisor) and to check user's permission to access records related to a specific railway station
- each of the OR group has, in average, two `exists()` checks with subqueries on some data related to the record and also to check the station permission
- when expanded to be human-readable, the query is about 200 lines long

Essentially, the availability of each record to currently logged-in user depends on the following factors:
- the company of the user
- the company of the carrier, consignee, consignor, payer of each specific consignment note
- every consignment note has multiple route sections and every section has its own carrier and payer, thus requiring further access control conditions to make these records visible to the user
- every consignment note and every route section has origin and destination stations, and a user is allowed to see the record only if he has been given access to any of these stations (using a simple relation table).

There are about 2 million consignment note records in the database and the customer is complaining that it takes too long to load a page with 20 records.

Unfortunately it is not possible to optimize the final query before passing it to the RDBMS (Oracle 11g, to be specific) because the system has complex architecture and a home-brew ORM tool, and the final query is being assembled in at least three different places that are responsible for collection of fields to select, collection of joins, adding criteria selected in the UI and, finally, the reason for this question - the permission related filter.

I wouldn't say that the final query is very complex; on the contrary, it is simple in its nature but it's just huge.

I'm afraid that caching solutions wouldn't be very effective in this case because data changes very often and the cache would be overwritten every minute or so. Also, because of individual permissions, each user should have own cache that would have to be maintained.

**Besides the usual recommendations - dealing with indexes and optimizing each subquery as much as possible - are there any other well-known solutions for filtering large amount of records based on complex permission rules?**

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents, since I see no other answers around.

First of all you would need to get the execution plan of the query. Without it, it's not that easy to have an idea of what could get improved. It sounds like a nice challenge, if it wasn't for your urgency.

Well, you say the query has 17 left joins. Does that mean there is a single main table in the query? If so, then that's the first section I would optimize. The key aspect is to reduce the `TABLE ACCESS BY ROWID` operations as much as possible on that table. The typical solution is to add well tailored indexes to narrow down the `INDEX RANGE SCAN` as much as possible on that table, therefore reducing the heap fetches.

Then, when navigating the rest of the [outer] tables (presumably using `NESTED LOOPS`) you can try materializing some of those conditions into simple 0/1 flags you could use, instead of the whole conditions.

Also, if you only need 20 rows, I would expect that to be very fast... well as long as the query is properly **pipelined**. If in your case it's taking too long, then it may not be the case. Are you sorting/aggregating/windowing by some specific condition that prevents pipelining? This condition could be the most important factor to index if you just need 20 rows.

Finally, you could try avoiding heap fetches by using "covering indexes". That could really improve performance of your query, but I would leave it as a last resort, since they have their downsides.

Well, again a good solution really requires to take a good look at the execution plan. If you still are game, post it, and I can look at it.